# Where are MongoDB shard key indexes located?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, sharding

In a MongoDB cluster, where are shard Key indexes located?

I guess they should be stored in the config servers, but I cannot find the answer in the Mongo documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Indexes are located on the instances where indexed documents are stored. Config servers keep ranges of the key per [chunk](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/config-database/#config.chunks).